# Mass applying conditional changes to matching rows

Tags: jquery

I need to apply a status next to a user's linked name which appears multiple times in table rows, as well as change the matching cell colors, whenever it is found that their last action on another page (user history page) is "signin" from a single performance of `.get()` per unique username url.

I am open to suggestions on how to do this, but I have been trying to do this by adding a `statusActive` class the first time this criteria is met on a unique username and then using an if statement to avoid loading the other page where it finds the user's last action each time. The problem is that it is not applying `statusActive` to all rows when the user's last action is "signin" and instead it is performing `.get()` for each row.

For example, if John Doe is listed in 5 rows, it is loading John Doe's user history page 5 times and then changing "John Doe" to "John Doe (signin)" on each row one-by-one, instead of looking him up once and mass applying at once the changes to all 5 rows.

Here is the relevant HTML for the table:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" id="picklist_group_list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Assigned user</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Completed at</th>
      <th>Picklist</th>
      <th>Order</th>
      <th>Zone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/picklist_group/display_picklist_group?picklist_group_id=123456">123456</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/labor_tracking/lookup_history?user_name=johndoe">johndoe</a>
      </td>
      <td>In progress</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/pack_by_picklist?picklist_id=43333332">43333332</a> (2 items)
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/view_order/111113">111113</a>
      </td>
      <td>books</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/picklist_group/display_picklist_group?picklist_group_id=123456">123456</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/labor_tracking/lookup_history?user_name=johndoe">johndoe</a>
      </td>
      <td>In progress</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/pack_by_picklist?picklist_id=222221">222221</a> (16 items)
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/view_order/111113">111113</a>
      </td>
      <td>books</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/picklist_group/display_picklist_group?picklist_group_id=123456">123456</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/labor_tracking/lookup_history?user_name=johndoe">johndoe</a>
      </td>
      <td>In progress</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/pack_by_picklist?picklist_id=456456">456456</a> (3 items)
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/view_order/2233321">2233321</a>
      </td>
      <td>books</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/picklist_group/display_picklist_group?picklist_group_id=123456">123456</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/labor_tracking/lookup_history?user_name=johndoe">johndoe</a>
      </td>
      <td>In progress</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/pack_by_picklist?picklist_id=9999999996">9999999996</a> (13 items)
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/view_order/323">323</a>
      </td>
      <td>books</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/picklist_group/display_picklist_group?picklist_group_id=123456">123456</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/labor_tracking/lookup_history?user_name=johndoe">johndoe</a>
      </td>
      <td>In progress</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/pack_by_picklist?picklist_id=09987">09987</a> (1 item)
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/view_order/3333111">3333111</a>
      </td>
      <td>books</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/picklist_group/display_picklist_group?picklist_group_id=987654">987654</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/labor_tracking/lookup_history?user_name=janedoe">janedoe</a>
      </td>
      <td>In progress</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/pack_by_picklist?picklist_id=124998">124998</a> (11 items)
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/view_order/9906">9906</a>
      </td>
      <td>food</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/picklist_group/display_picklist_group?picklist_group_id=987654">987654</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/labor_tracking/lookup_history?user_name=janedoe">janedoe</a>
      </td>
      <td>In progress</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/pack_by_picklist?picklist_id=66342">66342</a> (10 items)
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/wms/view_order/323">323</a>
      </td>
      <td>food</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
var userId = "#picklist_group_list tbody td:nth-child(2) a";
var userIdCell = "#picklist_group_list tbody td:nth-child(2)";
var statusActive = { backgroundColor : "#339933", color : "#fff" };

$(userId).each(function(index) {
    var userIdUrl = "https://www.url.com" + $(this).attr("href");
    if (!$(userId).eq(index).hasClass("statusChecked")) {
        $.get(userIdUrl, function(data) {
            var lastAction = $(data).find(".reportLayout > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)").text();

            if (lastAction == "signin") {
                $(userIdCell).eq(index).css(statusActive);
                $(userId).eq(index).css(statusActive).after(" (" + lastAction + " )").addClass("statusChecked");
            };
        });
    };
});
```

I think the problem is with using `.eq(index)` for the two lines in if `(lastAction == "signin")` but I can't figure out how to apply `.css` and `.addClass` to all rows that match that specific user.

Thank you for any help in advanced!

**EDIT:** Relevant HTML added.

Comment: It would really help to see some HTML (reduced to the relevant parts) as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have added the relevant HTML and will get to work on reading your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you pretty far, I think.

```js
// returns a promise for the last user action
function getLastUserAction(link) {
    return $.get("https://www.url.com" + link).then(function (data) {
        return $(data).find(".reportLayout > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)").text();
    });
}

const userStatus = {};
$("#picklist_group_list tbody td:nth-child(2) a:not(.statusChecked)").each(function () {
    var self = this,
        userName = $(this).text();
    
    // make a single HTTP request per distinct username & store it...
    if (!(userName in userStatus)) userStatus[userName] = getLastUserAction($(this).attr("href"));

    // ...but register a "done" callback for each cell
    userStatus[userName].done(function (lastAction) {
        if (lastAction === "signin") $(self).addClass("statusActive").after(`(${lastAction})`);
        $(self).addClass("statusChecked");
    });
});
```

Add CSS classes for `.statusActive` and possibly `.statusChecked`, too.

```css
.statusActive {
    background-color: #339933;
    color: #fff;
}
```

---

You could additionally add a loading indicator and error handling:

```css
.loading {
    /* e.g. add a spinner via background-image */
}
.failed {
    /* e.g. add a exclamation mark via background-image */
}
```

and

```js
$(self).addClass(".loading");

userStatus[userName].done(function (lastAction) {
    if (lastAction === "signin") $(self).addClass("statusActive").after(`(${lastAction})`);
    $(self).addClass("statusChecked");
}).always(function () {
    $(self).removeClass("loading");
}).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
    $(self).addClass("failed").attr({title: error});
};
```

Comment: How can I store and use multiple values returned from getLastUserAction()? I have found that I need to return a timestamp from the same HTTP request, located at `.reportLayout > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1)`. e.g. final output: "John Doe (signin, 05:55)"

Comment: @Michael I would return an object: `return {lastAction: $(data).find(".reportLayout > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)").text(), timeStamp: $(data).find(".reportLayout > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1)").text() };`.